# Close/Minimize/Restore buttons not present

Tags: compiz

I was playing around with Compiz and now the Close/Minimize/Restore buttons are gone. Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seams your decorator has crashed. Try in a terminal:

```
compiz --replace &
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you used CompizConfig Settings Manager to change things make sure you have enabled window decorations - see first screen shot

[image]

I recommend you install Ubuntu Tweak it will enable you to change the window manager settings easily and arrange the button layout as you want - see screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: this worked for me as a permanent solution (didint have to install ubuntu tweak though) thanks!